# Upload Form to Firestore with Flutter

Tags: forms, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm confused about how to upload a form to Firestore in my flutter app.  I've gone through numerous tutorials and am able to login to Firebase and retrieve data from Firestore into my flutter app, but I can't figure out how to upload a Form with numerous Textfields to Firestore.

Example:  Document title "books"
Textfields would include:  Title, Author, etc.

***  // Below is my page which does import data from Firestore (This works).  I've added a button which goes to another page where I've attempted to add a form to upload to Firestore (This doesn't work).  The loading of the page works, but uploading to Firestore is not set up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';





class FireStore extends StatelessWidget {
  FireStore({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});
  final BaseAuth auth; 
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  void _signOut () async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print (e);
    }
  }





  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text ('Welcome'),
          actions: <Widget>[

          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: _signOut
          )
          ]
        ),
        body: new StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,


          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(document['author']),

            );

          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new UploadFormField()),
        );

      }
    )
      );
      }

} 



// UPLOAD TO FIRESTORE



class UploadFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadFormFieldState createState() => _UploadFormFieldState();
}

class _UploadFormFieldState extends State<UploadFormField> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
  bool _validate = false;
  String title, author;
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Upload'),
      ),
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
       child: new Container(
         margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
         child: new Form(
           key: _key,
           autovalidate: _validate,



         child: FormUI(

         )),
       ),


      ),

      ),
    );
  }
  Widget FormUI() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
          validator: validateTitle,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            title = val;
          }
        ),

        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Author'),
          validator: validateAuthor,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            author = val;
          }
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        new RaisedButton(onPressed: _sendToServer, child: new Text('Upload'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
  String validateTitle (String value) {
    String pattern = r' (^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0){
             return 'Title is required';

           } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
             return "Title must be a-z and A-Z";
           }

           return null;
  }

  String validateAuthor (String value) {
    String pattern = r' (^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0){
             return 'Author is required';

           } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
             return "Author must be a-z and A-Z";
           }

           return null;
  }


  _sendToServer(){
    if (_key.currentState.validate() ){
      //No error in validator
      _key.currentState.save();
      print ("Title $title");
      print ("Author $author");
    } else {
      // validation error
      setState(() {
              _validate = true;
            });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Post the Code you started with.

Comment: Here's the current code/form (I've simplified it).   If you scroll down about half ways, you'll see the class "UploadFormField".  That is where I'd assume I need to put the FIrestore data to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work it out with the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';





class FireStore extends StatelessWidget {
  FireStore({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});
  final BaseAuth auth; 
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  void _signOut () async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print (e);
    }
  }





  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text ('Welcome'),
          actions: <Widget>[

          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: _signOut
          )
          ]
        ),
        body: new StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,


          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(document['author']),

            );

          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new UploadFormField()),
        );

      }
    )
      );
      }

} 



// UPLOAD TO FIRESTORE



class UploadFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadFormFieldState createState() => _UploadFormFieldState();
}

class _UploadFormFieldState extends State<UploadFormField> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
  bool _validate = false;
  String title, author;

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Upload'),
      ),
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: new Form(
              key: _key,
              autovalidate: _validate,
              child: FormUI(),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget FormUI() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
          validator: validateTitle,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            title = val;
          }
        ),

        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Author'),
          validator: validateAuthor,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            author = val;
          }
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        new RaisedButton(onPressed: _sendToServer, child: new Text('Upload'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
  String validateTitle(String value) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Title is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Title must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }

   String validateAuthor(String value) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Author is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Author must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }


 _sendToServer(){
    if (_key.currentState.validate() ){
      //No error in validator
      _key.currentState.save();
      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
        CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('books');

        await reference.add({"Title": "$title", "Author": "$author"});
      });
    } else {
      // validation error
      setState(() {
              _validate = true;
            });
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's Firestore plugin takes Map as input for setData or add functions, so whatever data you have in class object or in other variables, you just need to convert it to map (or nested map for nested data structure) & give it to setData or add function as input to save in Firestore. For classes, flutter examples show mostly having "toMap()" function implemented in classes which simply return all the data class object have in the desired map structure, and its counterpart "fromMap(Map mapData)" which will be used to create object from map when you fetch data from Firestore later.

Eg.

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection(TBL_USERS)
    .add({
      "type": "Dog",
      "age": 6,
      "breed": "abc",
    });
```

Or since its map,  you can directly use any string (as long as its unique in the map) as key

Eg.

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection(TBL_USERS)
    .add({
      "Dog": {
              "age": 6,
              "breed": "abc",
             },
      "Cat" : {
              "age": 2,
              "breed": "xyz",
             },
    });
```

Comment: Where would I put this in my code?   My "upload" section is in the Class "UploadFormField".

Comment: Also, I've used the example from Firestore with "books" as the document name and "Title" and "Author" within the textfields.